# Why its typical to extend functions when behavior could be implemented in the only function

Tags: solidity

Typical implementation from openzappelin

```
    function _setOwner(address newOwner) private {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _setOwner(newOwner);
    }
```

Why not to implement the same behavior with the only function (including functionality of both)?

```
    function _setOwner(address newOwner) private {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_setOwner(address)` private function is also invoked from `renounceOwnership()`, passing it the zero address value.

So it's a matter of creating reusable private functions, rather than assigning into a set of properties (even though this snippet assigns to just one property) from different places.

Comment: Clear answer. Thank you!